# Shortcut to create new window instance of VSCode on Mac

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have searched extensively, but none of the answers I found seem to address my specific need. I am looking for a straightforward way to create a new instance of Visual Studio Code (VSCode) on my Mac using a keyboard shortcut or some other convenient method. Can someone please provide a step-by-step guide or a clear explanation of how to achieve this? Please see screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open `Code > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts` on Mac, or `File > Preferences > …` on Windows.
2. Type in name of the command (*"New Window"*, in your case).
3. Select relevant entry (`workbench.action.newWindow` in your case).
4. Press enter (or click `+`) and assign it your desired key combination or chord in opened modal prompt.

---

Alternatively you can use the **Command Palette** to get to the Keyboard Shortcut settings directly:

1. find the command in the Command Palette,,
2. focus (hover) it,
3. press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to focus (hover) the "gearbox" icon on the right side,
4. and invoke (enter / click) that "⚙".

---

BTW, in case you intend to open **existing** workspace (and not start a new one from scratch), then you can use

```
File: Open Recent
```

(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, not sure about Mac binding), what offers you most recent workspaces / folders.
Then you can open selected one **to a new window** (instead of switching the current) using **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>**+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (again, not sure about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on Mac here).

Comment: I realized that I had double mapped the keyboard shortcut. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard Shortcuts on Mac, or File > Preferences > … on Windows.
Type in name of the command ("New Window", in your case).
Select relevant entry (workbench.action.newWindow in your case).
Press enter (or click +) and assign it your desired key combination or chord in opened modal prompt.